# insert uid into column based

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables in postgresql looks something like below. please help me with the query to insert into table `1uid` column based on column `name2`.

```
table 1         table 2
|uid|name1|     |uid|name2|table 1uid|
| 1 | a  |     | 1 | b    |          |
| 2 | b  |     | 2 | C    |          |
| 3 | c  |     | 3 | a    |          |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword you need to look for is Update (which changes existing rows).  Insert is for creating brand new rows.

But for your particular case, something along the lines of:

```
update table2 set table1uid = (select uid from table1 where table1.name1 = table2.name2)
```